# How to modify .doc or .docx file in php

Tags: php, tabs

I have to modify the uploaded `.doc` or `.docx` file in `php`. I googled but i only found how to read that but not as it is.
  I want the word file as it is and put text at the bottom of that MS Word file. 
 How is this possible anyone know please reply.

Thanks,

---

I have used following code :-

```
$w='Test';
$fp = fopen('c:/text.doc', 'a+');
fwrite($fp, $w);
fclose($fp);
```

It appended the string but not showing in the word document. 
When i changed the extension of **doc** file to **xml** then it shows the string at the end.
why should not it showing in doc file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

For Docx files, you can easily use an zip reader such as [TbsZip](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/tools.php) in order to read and edit the main XML sub-file (Docx files are actually zip archive files). For DOC files, it is very difficult because it is a binary file.

Here is an example of code with TbsZip:

```
<?php

$x = "Hello World!";

include_once('tbszip.php');

$zip = new clsTbsZip();

// Open the document
$zip->Open('mydoc.docx');
$content = $zip->FileRead('word/document.xml');
$p = strpos($content, '</w:body>');
if ($p===false) exit("Tag </w:body> not found in document.");

// Add the text at the end
$content = substr_replace($content, '<w:p><w:r><w:t>'.$x.'</w:t></w:r></w:p>', $p, 0);
$zip->FileReplace('word/document.xml', $content, TBSZIP_STRING);

// Save as a new file
$zip->Flush(TBSZIP_FILE, 'new.docx');
```

Answer (score 2):

Documents in the DOCX format should be XML (zipped), so you can try to parse and modify them...

See [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) for details about the format.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Actualy i am uploading the .doc file and insert some data in that doc file at the end.
And then the insert the url of .doc file into database. Then when i want that .doc file i will download that. If i convert it to xml the how it change in word document.

Comment: Word documents are XML. At least from MS Word 2007. And even 2003 was some kind of XML already but probably not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I recommend saving files as XML. When you write a document in MS Word, go Save As -> Other Formats -> Choose XML here.

You will be still able to open the document in MS Word and it will be easy to edit XML with PHP DOM or SimpleXML.

To add some text at the bottom, you just need to add a new w:p element to the XML body:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00CF175F" w:rsidRDefault="00CF175F">
<w:r>
<w:t>New text to be added</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
```

W is a namespace. For Word 2007+ it is:

```
http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main
```

In the older XML format there are different namespaces so you will have to look at MS web pages to find which one is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have same task to edit **.doc** or **.docx** file in php, i have use this code for it.

**Reference** :  http://www.onlinecode.org/update-docx-file-using-php/

```
    $full_path = 'template.docx';
    //Copy the Template file to the Result Directory
    copy($template_file_name, $full_path);

    // add calss Zip Archive
    $zip_val = new ZipArchive;

    //Docx file is nothing but a zip file. Open this Zip File
    if($zip_val->open($full_path) == true)
    {
        // In the Open XML Wordprocessing format content is stored.
        // In the document.xml file located in the word directory.

        $key_file_name = 'word/document.xml';
        $message = $zip_val->getFromName($key_file_name);               

        $timestamp = date('d-M-Y H:i:s');

        // this data Replace the placeholders with actual values
        $message = str_replace("client_full_name",      "onlinecode org",       $message);
        $message = str_replace("client_email_address",  "ingo@onlinecode.org",  $message);
        $message = str_replace("date_today",            $timestamp,             $message);      
        $message = str_replace("client_website",        "www.onlinecode.org",   $message);      
        $message = str_replace("client_mobile_number",  "+1999999999",          $message);

        //Replace the content with the new content created above.
        $zip_val->addFromString($key_file_name, $message);
        $zip_val->close();
    }
```